# Assign key & value for list?

Tags: python, dictionary

here is my program so far:

```
file = open('CASS.txt', 'r')
f = file.readlines()
file.close()

classcode = input('Please enter a class code: ' )

print("Class list for", classcode)
for line in f:
    if line.find(classcode)>=0:
        names = line.split()
        names1 = names[0].split(',')[0:3]
        print(names1)
```

and the output for class TDA3M102 is

```
['Abdull', 'Sonia', 'F']
['Armstrong', 'Sammi', 'F']
['Barrey', 'Tina', 'F']
['Bu', 'Kyle', 'M']
['Cheng', 'Henry', 'M']
['Dance', 'Daniel', 'M']
['East', 'Adam', 'M']
['Frasier', 'Annie', 'F']
['Han', 'Brandon', 'M']
['Huang', 'Peter']
['Kauffman', 'Fredricka', 'F']
['Lunsford', 'Mike', 'M']
['Leung', 'Dan', 'M']
['Li', 'Annika', 'F']
['Li', 'Ben', 'M']
['Muhummad', 'Artom', 'M']
['Nguyen', 'Tim', 'M']
['Peterson', 'Elena']
['Shneider', 'Samantha', 'F']
['Sun', 'Yu', 'M']
['Vance', 'Adam', 'M']
['Wen', 'William', 'M']
['Woods', 'Larry', 'M']
['Yan', 'Harry']
```

I have to convert this list into a dictionary and assign the first name & last name for each student as a key and gender as value. If there is no gender, the program should set a random gender.. I'm not really sure how to go about this. Any ideas?

Here's what I tried:

```
myDict = {}

for name in names1:
    if name in myDict:
        myDict[name] += 1
    else:
        myDict[name] = 1

print(myDict)
```

and the output was:

```
{'Yan': 1, 'Harry': 1}
```

for some reason it only recognizes 1 name (last name in the list) and only outputs the values for that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to figure out if there is a gender? How to choose a random one? How to make a dictionary?

Comment: @li.davidm I've tried using a for statement and looping it into a new dictionary but it only does it for one name (usually the last name) and crashes. I also have a feeling that I should use .setdefault for setting a gender for the names that don't have one.. the genders should be random if they aren't given one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do somehting like this:

```
names1 = [['Abdull', 'Sonia', 'F'],
        ['Armstrong', 'Sammi', 'F'],
        ['Barrey', 'Tina', 'F'],
        ['Bu', 'Kyle', 'M'],
        ['Cheng', 'Henry', 'M'],
        ['Dance', 'Daniel', 'M'],
        ['Huang', 'Peter']]


import random

myDict = {}

for lname,*rest in names1:
    fname = rest[0]
    gender = rest[1] if len(rest) == 2 else random.choice(['M','F'])

    key = fname + ' ' + lname
    if key not in myDict:
        myDict[key] = gender
    else:
        print("Student {} already exists!".format(key))



print(myDict)
```

This gives:

```
{'Sonia Abdull': 'F', 'Sammi Armstrong': 'F', 'Tina Barrey': 'F', 'Daniel Dance': 'M', 'Peter Huang': 'M', 'Henry Cheng': 'M', 'Kyle Bu': 'M'}
```

Comment: when i tried this with the rest of the code it only came out with the key:value for the last name in the list like this: {'a H': 'M', 'a Y': 'n'}